# How to write unit tests supporting Javascript 6 modules

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, ecmascript-6

My Javascript codebase is based on new [ES6 Modules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import).

So I have Javascript files like this for example:

```
export class MyClass {
  constructor() {
    this.list = [];
  }

  add(el) { this.list.push(el); }
}
```

As a module, I import this file in other Javascript files like this:

```
import * as lists from "./myclass";
```

And inside an HTML page, the following syntax has to be used:

```
<script src="myclass.js" type="module"></script>
```

### Unit testing

I need a framework for testing my code. The problem is that I am using Javascript 6 modules, so modern frameworks like [karma](https://karma-runner.github.io/1.0/index.html) have problems as they import the files not as modules:

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
    files: [
      'src/**/*.js',
      'test/**/*.js'
    ],
    ...
  })
}
```

Above is an example of `karma.conf.js`. In the specific case of Karma, the runner will not import the files as modules, thus the injection in page fails.

What unit test frameworks can I use for testing Javascript 6 modules?

Comment: have you tried jest?

Comment: What are you trying to test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check out [Jest](https://facebook.github.io/jest/), it's Facebook's test framework that allows you to run your tests on Node (with [JSDOM](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom)).

It runs your tests in parallel and without browser, therefore suppose to be much faster.

Comment: Works perfectly!

Comment: Hey @Andry, glad you got it working. Can you elaborate on what you did to get it to work? I started with Jest and switched to Mocha when I ran into a problem trying to test my ES modules. I thought I'd have to use Babel, etc. With Mocha I found the ESM library and hoped to use "mocha 'lib.test.js' --require esm' as I'd seen a blog post that used this solution, but it has not worked for me. blog post: https://alxgbsn.co.uk/2019/02/22/testing-native-es-modules-mocha-esm/

Comment: @AndrewCastellano Hey man it was some time ago and I deleted the project so I don’t remember :(

Answer (score 2):

I'm using a combination of Mocha and Babel - Babel transpiles the ES6 modules to code Mocha can work with, and so you can use `import` in the test files.

To run mocha with the Babel transpiler:

```
mocha --compilers js:babel-core/register --recursive test/*
```

I'm pretty sure other frameworks have a similar solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure Jest actually supports modules, right? I.e. I want my test files .. those with the assertions .. to be able to import modules which also import other modules.

It seems the best you can do with node based testing frameworks, with I think may be all of them, is us pretty awful babel/webpack stunts which I'd really prefer not to use.

Headless Chrome certainly seems to be interesting, as does Puppeteer

- https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer
- https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/06/headless-karma-mocha-chai

Comment: BTW: My current solution is this: my repo uses Rollup to create three "bundles": IIFE (for script tags), es6 (a one-file module for all my "sub modules"), and a .cjs (commonJS) bundle for use in node. I just use the latter for testing. But another repo does need browser testing so I'm going to look at the two urls above.